# Attribute Not Updating with NumberControl

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have an Attribute that is designed to be controlled by a Number Control Attribute

```
<NumberControl
  label={__("SM")}
  onChange={(value) => setAttributes({ SM: value })}
  value={attributes.SM}
  help={__("Response SM Setting for Column")}
  min={0}
  max={12}
/>;
```

Is there something I am doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to add **parseInt** to the value while updating the attributes. Check it here I have fixed the issue.

```
<NumberControl
    label={ __( 'SM' ) }
    onChange={ ( value ) => setAttributes( { SM: parseInt(value) } ) }
    value={ attributes.SM }
    help={ __( 'Response SM Setting for Column' ) }
    min={ 0 }
    max={ 12 }
/>
```